# SMS Retriever API - permanent listener

Tags: android, google-play, sms, android-permissions

From the documentation it says that the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) is only listening up to 5  minutes.

> The SMS retrieval task will listen for up to five minutes for an SMS message that contains a unique string that identifies your app.

**Is it possible to have it running all the time?**
Is it bad for battery life if I boot it up every five minutes?

Use case is receiving an SMS request that responds to SMS with location. We use SMS, not data, because our users are often in areas without data network.
I am unable to get RECEIVE_SMS permission on Google Play (what I gather from "update rejected" email), but they will allow SEND_SMS.

Comment: Just a suggestion , Instead of SMS why not use firebase  notifications?

Comment: I use SMS for emergency situations where mobile data is not available, but GSM still works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible to keep it running longer than 5 minutes.

Also, it listens for only one SMS with OTP, so it doesn't make sense even if it would have been longer than 5 minutes.

If you have a `resend OTP` or `retry` functionality, you need to start the SMS retriever again with below code.

```
val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)
val retriever = client.startSmsRetriever()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to have it running all the time? Is it bad for battery life if I boot it up every five minutes?** -- By Using **JobSchedular** You can run continously in foreground upto 15 min, After that you have to restart the **JobSchedular** **again**.. If you to like this.. after some Android Device says "this app is **POWER CONSUMING APP** you wanna close??? .. "

Comment: From the app update rejection email I gathered they will allow a SEND_SMS exception for my app, but not RECEIVE_SMS.

Running JobScheduler every 15 minutes means that the app will not get the SMS in this 10 minute period

Comment: For receive SMS we cant run more time in background.. By Using JobSchedular You can run continously in foreground upto 15 min, After that you have to restart the JobSchedular again..